# Why does copying file directly is not editable?

Tags: linux, root, cp

```
mkdir ~/.config/dunst

sudo cp /etc/dunst/dunstrc ~/.config/dunst/dunstrc
```

This makes the file not editable

```
rm ~/.config/dunst/dunstrc
touch ~/.config/dunst/dunstrc
sudo cp /etc/dunst/dunstrc ~/.config/dunst/dunstrc
```

This makes the file editable. Why does linux behave in this way?

Comment: ls -l ~/.config/dunst/dunstrc and check permissions. Your question means you dont know about file owners and permissions. Read about them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most modern operating systems apply [file permissions and ownership](https://linuxhandbook.com/linux-file-permissions/). In Linux, as on Unix, the default behaviour is to restrict access to files unless told to share them (other operating systems take a different approach). By using "sudo" you are carrying out operations without any safety controls. Sudo performs a command as the root user. When you copy a file as root, the new file is owned by root. The file is still editable - but not by other users than root. You can...

- edit the file as root (usually bad)
- change the user (or group if group writeable) ownership of the file to user you normally use (or a group they are a member of) (good)
- change the permissions of the file so anyone can edit it (bad)
- change the defaults for file permissions (bad)

Changing the ownership is done with the [chown](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chown.1.html) command. Changing the permissions on the file is done with [chmod](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html). Changing the defaults is done with the [umask](https://linuxcommandlibrary.com/man/umask) command, typically invoked from your shell profile. chmod and chown are illustrated in the first link, and in more detail in the subsequent links.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo cp` will make it belong to the original user of the file (most likely `root`).

`sudo` after `touch` will overwrite the file, thus it'll retain its original id/groupid.

"Clobber" is the default action though it's not clearly indicated in the man page:

```
       -n, --no-clobber
              do not overwrite an existing file (overrides a previous -i option)
```

This should fix that:

```bash
sudo chown `id -u` ~/.config/dunst/dunstrc
```